# How to return response to function from .then() in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, response

The check() is called from the html, and the return value should be true/false.

```
ng-class="{'timeline-inverted: check(id)'}"
```

The `$scope.server.get()` get `result(r)` from the server script, and I need to return the `$scope.result` to the `check()` function.

Here is my code in angular:

```
$scope.check = _.memoize(function(userId) {
    $scope.server.get({
        action: 'checkif',
        userID: userId
    }).then(function successHandler(r) {
        $scope.result = r.data.result;
    });
    return $scope.result;   // $scope.result is undefined
});
```

Comment: your return should be inside the .then Have you tried it?

Comment: @Fix3r yes, not working.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Promise than you resolve once the HTTP call is successful.

```
$scope.check = _.memoize(function(userId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $scope.server.get({
      action: 'checkif',
      userID: userId
    }).then(function successHandler(r) {
      resolve(r.data.result);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `memoize` doesnt realy make sense here. It is currently caching the returning `promise` instead of the returned data.

Comment: I have never used lodash, I'm just giving the usual way of returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

First, using [memoize](http://underscorejs.org/#memoize) is not a good deal here. memoized works perfectly fine as the argument has a primitive type. Since you call your API you cannot be sure that the same set of data is returned by the same `userId` & `action` params!

I don't know why your `$http` call is binded to an `$scope`. Maybe it better to place such stuff in a service. Finally your application could look like this nice structured app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, user) {

   $scope.userData = null;

   user.get('checkif', 2).then(function (result) {
      $scope.userData = result.data.result;
   });
});


myApp.service('user', function () {
  this.get = function (action, userId) {
    return $http({
      url: 'http://your-api-endpoint/',
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        action: action,
        userID: userId
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: i cant use url in my application..

Comment: Why can't you use URL in your application and how do you get your API result so?